# Android Studio started requiring me to press Run or Debug twice to correctly run or debug the app

Tags: android-studio

When I have the app I'm designing running and I hit run, Android Studio stops the app and installs the new one. It won't run it though. Same if I hit Debug. Takes two times. How do I fix this? Invalidating caches didn't help.

Update: Version 4.0.1 didn't have this issue, but now it is back with 4.1.

Comment: I believe it may be related to this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173912349